# How to recover latest pushed commit SHA1, even on "detached HEAD" state?

Tags: git, head

In a script currently under development, I need to recover latest pushed commit SHA1 on my current branch and therefore ignore local commits IDs.

When working on a local/remote branch, this is quite simple, many posts already answered this question.

For now, on a local or remote branch, I am using the following command :

```
git log --format=format:%H -n1 @{u}
```

However, my script need to work as well on a "detached HEAD" state. With the previous command, I am not able to get latest pushed commit in that case (which would be the one pointed after `HEAD detached at`). A simple `git log HEAD` wouldn't be enough as I want to ignore local commits.

It would be better if I don't modify the branch state either (e.g. `git checkout -b myBranch`).

I am using GIT version 2.17.1.

Comment: Can you explain it further please. You'd like to get the latest pushed/remote commit? Your remote branches can have a detached HEAD? As of my understanding now: `git log --remotes --format=%H -1`

Comment: Let's explain it with a scenario. Let's say I am working on master branch, pointing to origin/master. I must checkout a commit, and then go to a "HEAD detached at XYZ". Once there, I commit some modifications. With the command I am looking for, I would like to get "XYZ" as ouput. 
The command you suggested returns the my origin/HEAD sha1 which is the latest commit I see from master in origin.

Comment: Ok. So you'd like to get the commit before your commit to the detached HEAD? `git log --format=%H HEAD~1 -1`

Comment: In the case of my scenario, yes. But my script should be work with 1,2,3 ... any number of local commits, even 0. The thing is, I would like to get from what commit I have been detached in general.

Comment: You can parse the output of `git status` or `git branch`: `HEAD detached from xxxxxxx`. When you know your previous branch you can use `git merge-base previous HEAD`

Comment: I am implementing a workaround to parse ```git branch``` right now, that is the only way I found to do it. That command is doing what I want, but only with a HEAD detached : ```$(git rev-parse $(echo $(git branch | sed -n 's/^\* //p') | grep -Eo "[0-9a-z]{9,}"))``` I tried to find a trick with merge-base command, but it didn't exactly suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you rule out

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

for some reason?

Because in many cases it's the plumbing equivalent of `log`'s porcelain.

Also maybe check the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse).

Comment: I already tried this command, but it returned the latest commit SHA1 on the temporary branch, but I do not want this one as it is a local commit. But indeed, I can use it instead of the command that I am currently using.

Comment: @fpiat OK I get it better, I'll have to rethink this and adapt.